# How to specify multiple paths to an table in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, path

To make it clear, I'm asking about the syntax of Spark SQL instead of Spark DataFrame.

We know that Spark SQL can query a parquet (text, etc.) table directly and below is an example. What if there are 2 paths that I want to use as a single table?

```
select
    *
from
    parquet.`path_1`
```

Comment: Do those different paths represent partitions of the same table or was the data just split between two folders?

Comment: @Sai The data was split into 2 directories.

Answer (score 1):

This is in python, so i can show the variables, but the SQL portion will be the same. I'm assuming that you'd just want the data to append onto itself? if so:

```py
pth1 = '/path/to/location1/part-r-00000-bf53578.gz.parquet'
pth2 = '/path/to/location2/part-r-00001-bf265.gz.parquet'
sqlContext.sql("""
    select * from parquet.`hdfs://{0}` 
    union 
    select * from  parquet.`hdfs://{1}`
    """.format(pth1,pth2)).show()
+----+----+------------+
|col1|col2|        col3|
+----+----+------------+
|   2|   b|9.0987654321|
|   1|   a| 4.123456789|
+----+----+------------+
```

in ONLY spark-sql it'd look like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM parquet.`hdfs:///path/to/location1/part-r-00000-bf53578.gz.parquet`
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM parquet.`hdfs:///path/to/location2/part-r-00001-bf265.gz.parquet`
```

Comment: Thank you, James. I do know this solution but it feels awkward. Since Spark DataFrame API supports reading multiple paths into a single DataFrame, I expect there to be a similar solution here.